# Zookeeper backed shared map (small KeyValue storage)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have bunch of `Hadoop MapReduce` applications (jobs) that need to share some 'living' small key-value storage. Actually it is about string ID being generated based on some string criteria during the progress of the job.

So it looks like shared `Map<String,String>` which can be modified and values are shared among `MapReduce` job components (mappers in my case but it does not matter).

Approach I see as visible is `Apache ZooKeeper`. I already have this service available on my `Hadoop` cluster. What I need in this case is reliable `ZooKeeper`-powered `KeyValue` storage. Currently I see it as one of declared applications but I don't see good implementation. Any suggestion? I see I need ephemeral node in this case (as MapReduce job has limited life time).

What I have found as best option currently is `Curator` framework which contains `SharedValue` class which looks like what I need. But I don't see any example of using it either in recipes or examples. Any example?

Any other good implementation approach or ready out-of-the-box solution for this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it you want to share and sync the id of the jobs b/w different machines?

Comment: Job ID is shared even without my influenc. It is about MapReduce. I want to share some kind of mini-storage between mappers and I don't want yet another service for this. ZK is already present so it looks like appropriate solution. Question is if we can do better?